# How to change Button's Text and Text's Text in a scene after loading it

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I want to change the value of Text after loading the fxml file.EnglishQuestions class is the controller of my Question.fxml file.Please ignore the argument of Button I just used it to load my previous Scene's Stage.

I am using this code but nothing is happening I want to change the button's text and Text's text after every minute after loading the fxml file, but whenever I try to change the text it's giving me error.Here I tried to change the questionText's Text but it didn't work.

```
    package try1;

    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Statement;
    import javafx.fxml.FXML;
    import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
    import javafx.scene.Parent;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;
    import javafx.scene.text.Text;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;


    public class EnglishQuestions {
        @FXML
        Text questionText;
        @FXML
        Button option1;
        @FXML
        Button option2;
        @FXML
        Button option3;
        @FXML
        Button option4;


      public void englishQuestions1(Button btn) throws Exception{
    //String q;
    //String op1,op2,op3,op4,ans;

     //loading FXML
        Stage window; 
          window =(Stage) btn.getScene().getWindow();
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Question.fxml"));
Scene scene = new Scene(root,900,600);
window.setScene(scene);
questionText.setText("What is your name? ");
window.show();
    }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the text in the controller that is associated with the FXML you loaded, not in the controller from which you loaded the FXML:

```
public void englishQuestions1(Button btn) throws Exception{
    Stage window; 
    window =(Stage) btn.getScene().getWindow();
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Question.fxml"));
    Parent root = loader.load();
    EnglishQuestions controller = (EnglishQuestions) loader.getController();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root,900,600);
    window.setScene(scene);
    controller.questionText.setText("What is your name? ");
    window.show();
}
```